# How to use jquery accordian in side bar first

Tags: search, navigation

[image: accordian with facest search]

I am using facets search filter. I want to use accordion in facest search filter.

Comment: Could you please more specific on your problem. As it currently stands we will not be able to understand your problem.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about implementing a functionality, or a layout seen in a site, for which only a screenshot or a site URL is provided. Please see [Help Center](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

As I understood you want to make it Collapsible.  If yes try below mentioned module

https://drupal.org/project/facetapi_collapsible

https://drupal.org/files/project-images/collapsible_facets_0.png

Comment: I do not want to use facetapi collapsible. i am using link with check box widget as accordion functionality.